# How do I save my model to use in another project in mlr3?

Tags: r, model, mlr3

### I would like to divide my working pipeline in 2:

1. One place (internal) where to benchmark and auto-tune the alrithms to select the final model.
2. Apply the selected models to new datasets (external).

For the second part, I will need to somehow save the resulting **model object** to later use
`model$predict_newdata()` and transporting it without needing to re-train the algorithm and taking with it the original training data.

The idea is synthesized with the following error:

```
library("mlr3")


task = tsk("iris")
learner = lrn("classif.rpart")


learner$train(task, row_ids = 1:120)

predictions = learner$predict(task, row_ids = 121:150)
predictions
```

So far so good, but now I have to save this model into an object outside the R Session, but of course, this won't work:

```
store_model = learner$model
save(store_model, 'model_rpart.RData')
```

Comment: Why does it not work? What error messages are you getting?

Comment: Better to save as an individual R object: saveRDS(store_model, 'model_rpart.RDS').  You can bring it back when needed with model <- readRDS('model_rpart.RDS').

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to save the whole object as an `.rds` object as [Brian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15344442/brian-montgomery) suggested.

```
saveRDS(learner, 'learner_rpart.rds')
 
model <- readRDS('learner_rpart.rds')

predictions = model$predict(task, row_ids = 121:150)
predictions$confusion
```